A question about changing something in language frameworks
In English linguistic's framework, Can we change something if something seems more suitable to us?
As we have different thoughts, we will not same in every point.
For example, if all supplements are called a special type of modifiers, will it be valid in the English linguistic?

It’s not clear what you’re really asking about here. You can of course change anything you want, but at some point you’d just be making your own framework, which others can then use, modify or criticise as they see fit. I don’t quite understand your example, because supplement is not a term that’s used with a specific meaning in linguistics, to my knowledge – did you mean complements? Those would not be considered modifiers in any framework I’m familiar with.

@JanusBahsJacquet Supplements are a sub-category of adjuct in The Cambridge grammar of English language book written by Hudson & pullum
